# Move symfony vendor outside the root project

Tags: symfony, vendor

I want to speed up my symfony2 project on my vagrant box, so I want to move my vendors outside the project folder.

I have install them in /home/vagrant/www/simtp/vendor, but I got a permission error when the autoload.php is included.

```
Warning: require(/home/vagrant/www/simtp/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/simtp/app/autoload.php on line 11

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/vagrant/www/simtp/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/simtp/app/autoload.php on line 11
```

I have already tested to change permission with chown, before it was "root", and now it is "www-data" (like the old vendor folder). I have already too tested to change chmod for 777.

But nothing work ... :/
Ps : My cache folder is empty.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: You used composer install?

Comment: Have you looked into sharing the entire project folder using rsync? That will speed it up the most.

Comment: Nawfal, Yes I use composer to install vendor in my symfony project.
Gerry, rsync is only unidirectional and terrible slow in my case, I don't know why. NFS is really fast but the files doesn't want to be updated if the file size doesn't change .. And I don't have "SendFile" config to On in Apache, and I don't use Sublime Text 3 with option "atomic save".

There is the reason why I want my vendor outside my project with the default sync folder with vagrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert in this, but since no one else replied, I think easiest solution would be moving vendor files to directory that is not in other user's home directory. in this case:
/home/vagrant/

to let's say:
/var/www-vendor/simtp/app/

this vendor directory should have chown compatible with apache worker (so it would have access)

you can also try solutions described here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91488/allow-a-user-to-read-some-other-users-home-directories

as far as I know despite standard permissions, user home directories are especially protected, that is the reason you have this issue.

you also didnt stated what linux distro you are using so you could consider adding this to your question so others would have less work to do.

Comment: After moved vendor folder (which has composer autoloader), don't forget to change the "src" directory in /vendor/composer/autoload_namespace.php.